# How to use iterator as a template parameter and return its value?

Tags: c++, iterator

Say I want to write a function like this:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Iterator_value> 
Iterator_value foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    vector<Iterator*> v(begin, end);
    do something
    return begin*;
}
```

This is just a demo, I know there are a lot of bugs. The question is:

- how to create a vector with only information about iterators?
- how to write a return value for iterator with a template?

Here is an example, I want to write a generic median function, and I want to return the exact value rather than return an iterator. Something like [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Moreover, I don't want to modify raw content, so I want to create a vector to copy iterator values. How can I create a vector with only iterators?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should not need the `Iterator_value` argument, instead use `Iterator::value_type` (or `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`) which every good iterator type should have. And learn the basics of iterators first (like how you "dereference" one). Lastly, if you want a vector of values, then use the value type, not pointers to `Iterator`.

Comment: In C++14 and later, you don't even need to specify a return type, just use `auto` and let the compiler deduce the return type. `auto` was added in C++11, but return type deduction was added in C++14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::iterator_traits`

```
template<typename Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    vector<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type> v(begin, end);
    //do something
    return *begin;
}
```

`auto` and `decltype` is an alternative:

```
template<typename Iterator>
decltype(auto) // C++14
foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
// or auto foo(..) -> decltype(*begin) in C++11
{
    std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(*begin)>> v(begin, end);
    //do something
    return *begin;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you so much!